# Group/Sort list of values into n groups of set size to maximize the difference between each value

Tags: matlab, sorting, optimization, grouping, mathematical-optimization

I have a data set of >100 points that needs to be grouped into a set number of groups. Each group has a maximum size but not all positions in the group need to be filled.

```
example = [7,10,8,2,6,19,34,2,5,45,23,9]
group_count = 5
group_size = 3
```

Breaking the data set into groups based on these rules one possibility is as follows. (random not optimized)

```
group1=[2,19,45]
group2=[5,8,23]
group3=[2,10]
group4=[7,9,34]
group5=[6]
```

The data set is broken into 5 groups with a max of 3 points in a group. The points in each group are ordered to sequentially increase.

Evaluation is based on the absolute difference between pairs of adjacent numbers in each group. When evaluating `group1=[2,19,45]` the absolute difference between the first two points is `19-2=17` the absolute difference between the second pair of points is `45-19=26`

If we do the same for all the groups the closest two points are `9-7=2` from `group4` and the farthest points are `45-19=26` from `group1`. You could also make an argument it is `group5` `6` because there is no other pair so it has infinite separation. The goal is to optimize the sorting method to maximize the minimum separation value.

To improve this solution we could take `9` from `group4`and add it into `group5`

```
group1=[2,19,45]
group2=[5,8,23]
group3=[2,10]
group4=[7,34]
group5=[6,9]
```

Now the new minimum separation between two points has increased from 2 to 3. This is an improvement in the solution. **The goal is to optimize the sorting method to maximize the minimum separation value.**

This problem has been solved in the past by brute force manual sorting (not ideal!). Looking to improve on this but I am not sure what methods to even look at.

Comment: Admin questions... Is it always safe to assume that `group_count * group_size >= numel(example)`? Also you say "you could also make an argument it is group5", well is it? Is that the definition you want to use or how should single-element groups be treated?

Comment: Your first question, yes, the group_count * group_size >= numel(example). There will always be more group "space" than points in this problem. The second question, a single element group is valid grouping and should be considered to be the highest level of optimization. If you had only 5 points and had 5 groups to put them in there would be no better solution.

Comment: While explaining this problem to someone else we came up with an analogy that illustrates it quite well. Think of every point as an arrival time of a plane, you have one terminal with "group_count" number of gates that can each only accept "group_size" number of planes in a day. How do you organize all of the incoming planes so you have the maximum amount of time between each incoming flight at that gate.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with ILP (via PuLP as I demonstrate; [matlab has equivalents](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html)). Due to your comment about "infinite distance", the minimum group assignment size has been set to 2. The produced solution for your sample data improves the minimum gap from 3 to 5.

```py
import pulp

values = [7, 10, 8, 2, 6, 19, 34, 2, 5, 45, 23, 9]
group_count = 5
group_size = 3
values_size = len(values)
values = tuple(sorted(values))

# The values are not unique, so they need to be given indices
value_idx = range(values_size)
group_idx = range(group_count)

assigns = pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
    name='assign_g%d_v%02d', indices=(group_idx, value_idx),
    cat=pulp.LpBinary,
)

lowest_diff = pulp.LpVariable(name='diff', cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='sort_binning', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
prob.setObjective(lowest_diff)

for group, row in zip(group_idx, assigns):
    n_assigns = pulp.lpSum(row)
    # Due to OP's "unitary group means infinite distance", mandate at least
    # two assignments per group
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'group_{group}_min', constraint=n_assigns >= 2,
    )
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'group_{group}_max', constraint=n_assigns <= group_size,
    )

for value in value_idx:
    prob.addConstraint(
        name=f'excl_v{value}', constraint=pulp.lpSum(
            assigns[group][value] for group in group_idx
        ) == 1,
    )

for start_idx, start_value in zip(value_idx[:-1], values[:-1]):
    for end_idx, end_value in zip(value_idx[start_idx+1:], values[start_idx+1:]):
        # big-M coefficient based on highest value in sub-sequence
        M = 2*(end_idx - start_idx + 1)*end_value

        for group, row in zip(group_idx, assigns):
            (
                start_assign, *inner_excludes, end_assign,
            ) = row[start_idx: end_idx+1]

            # Constrain lowest_diff <= end_value - start_value IFF
            #    start_assign == 1
            #    end_assign == 1
            #    sum(inner_excludes) == 0
            prob.addConstraint(
                name=f'diff_g{group}_{start_idx:02}_{end_idx:02}',
                constraint=lowest_diff <= end_value - start_value
                + M*(
                    pulp.lpSum(inner_excludes)
                    + (1 - start_assign)
                    + (1 - end_assign)
                )
            )

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

for group, row in zip(group_idx, assigns):
    print(f'Group {group}: ', ', '.join(
        str(value)
        for value, assign in zip(values, row)
        if assign.value() > 0.5
    ))
```

```
...
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                5.00000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               381
Time (CPU seconds):             0.06
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.07

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.06   (Wallclock seconds):       0.07

Group 0:  6, 45
Group 1:  5, 10, 19
Group 2:  8, 23, 34
Group 3:  2, 9
Group 4:  2, 7
```